# Magento 2 Auto deploy Script using capistrano or other tools

Tags: magento2, deploy, deployment

Does anyone have a script which will deploy magento2 to the server using Capistrano or other auto deploy scripts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We successfully used this one to deploy magento 2 single server projects: https://github.com/davidalger/capistrano-magento2 by @davidalger. It also supports multiservers setup, but we havent yet look into it.

A very good info about it you can find it here: http://davidalger.com/development/magento/deploying-magento-2-using-capistrano/.

Comment: Agreed in regards to the link only comment, however the material referenced is pretty useful. This answer didn't deserve a negative in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

This is in german but should be workable

http://slideshare.net/rhutterer/magento-capistrano-46254101

Comment: Is it for magento2??

Comment: No sorry it's not but i am working on a version for Magento2.

Comment: Thank @roman204

Comment: @roman204 any updates on Magento2 + Capistrano?

Comment: Magento2 + Capistrano is available here: https://github.com/davidalger/capistrano-magento2

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano is a very common deploy tool to deploy anything, but I prefer [Magallanes](https://github.com/magephp/magallanes). It is written in PHP and seems very easy (for me) to extend with my custom tasks.

But you can see that is lack of documentation, I have to check their code to learn about the flow and realise that they are absolutely compatiable to [GitLab CI](https://gitlab.com) - my current solution for CI/CD.

Here is my example Magallanes environment for a live Magento 2 site:

```
# staging environment
deployment:
  strategy: git-remote-cache
  user: www-data
  port: 10220
  from: ./
  to: /srv/users/www/apps/magento2
extras:
  enabled: true
  directory: shared
  vcs:
    enabled: true
    kind: git
    repository: git@gitlab.com:company/magento2.git
    branch: master
    remote: origin
    directory: repo
  magento:
    enabled: false # do not enable this, don't ask me why
    app_path: bin/magento
    version: 2 # leave this alone if you are deploying magento 2
  shared:
    enabled: true
    linking_strategy: absolute
    linked_files:
      - app/etc/env.php
      - app/etc/config.php
      - var/.magento_cronjob_status
      - var/.setup_cronjob_status
      - var/.update_cronjob_status
      - sitemap.xml
    linked_folders:
      - pub/media
      - var/backups
      - var/composer_home
      - var/importexport
      - var/import_history
      - var/log
      - var/session
      - var/tmp
releases:
  enabled: true
  max: 10
  symlink: public # symlink of current version in release directory
  directory: releases
hosts:
  - ssh-alias-in-ssh-config # it is ssh alias in ~/.ssh/config, say goodbye to enter password every single time
tasks:
  pre-deploy:
  on-deploy:
  post-release: # before the script create release folder
    - composer/update
    - magento/set-permissions
    - filesystem/link-shared-files
    - magento/production-setup # it is compatiable to magento 2.1 actually, if you aren't, use your custom tasks
  post-deploy:
```

In the real life, your remote directory will look like this after deployed.

```
magento2
├── @public -> releases/20160920093107/
├── releases
│   ├── 20160920092207
│   └── 20160920093107
├── shared
│   ├── app
│   ├── pub
│   ├── repo
│   ├── var
│   └── sitemap.xml
└── something_secret
```

So, that's it.
This is how I automate my deployment workflow with Magento 2 and the others.

If you need more supports and documentations, I recommend you go with Capistrano. (it supports Magento 2, check the links in #2 answer, I myself tested it and it works very well but it is slower than Magallanes)

Cheers.

Comment: Structure wise it's similar to Capistrano. Definitely, Capistrano has big user-base which is a plus as compared to this.